# Ruby .each method on Array from split string

Tags: arrays, ruby, while-loop, split, each

I'm having trouble using the .each method on an array that results of a string.split

```
def my_function(str)
    words = str.split
    return words #=> good, morning
    return words[words.count-1] #=> morning

    words.each do |word|
        return word
    end
end

puts my_function("good morning") #=> good
```

With any multi-word string, I only get the 1st word, not each of the words. With this example, I don't understand why I don't get "good" and "morning" when the 2nd item clearly exists in the array.

Similarly, using a while loop gave me the same result.

```
def my_function(str)

words = str.split
i = 0
while i < words.count
    return word[i]
    i += 1
end

puts my_function("good morning") # => good
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return` immediately exits the function.  What are you trying to accomplish with the `return` statement?

Comment: In the first example, with `return words`, the array is returned. Using `p my_function("good morning")` to print is more clear.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement in ruby is used to return one or more values from a Ruby Method. So your method will exit from `return words`.

```
def my_function(str)
    words = str.split
    return words # method will exit from here, and not continue, but return value is an array(["good", "morning"]).
    return words[words.count-1] #=> morning
    ....
end

puts my_function("good morning")
```

output:

```
good
morning
```

if you want to use `each` method to output words, you can do like this:

```
def my_function(str)
    str.split.each do |word|
        puts word
    end
end
```

or

```
def my_function(str)
    str.split.each { |word| puts word }
end

my_function("good morning")
```

output:

```
good
morning
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that `return words` returns the array to your outer `puts` function which is true. However once you return, you leave the function and never go back unless you explicitly call `my_function()` again (which you aren't) in which case you would start from the beginning of the function again.

If you want to print the value while staying in the function you will need to use

```
def my_function(str)
    words = str.split
    puts words #=> good, morning
    puts words[words.count-1] #=> morning

    words.each do |word|
        puts word # print "good" on 1st iteration, "morning" on 2nd
    end
end

my_function("good morning")
```